# not able to build, "gen" folder not found

Tags: java, parsing, intellij-idea, compiler-errors, javacc

I am trying to extend a java code with InteliJ to finally have my own one, but I am having many problems for building the project. I cannot find the folder "gen" neither "slf4j", and I am not able to compile the original code. I think it is related to the parser, but I do not know how this is working, if it should automatically be compiled or I should do something manually. I am pretty new on that, can anyone help me, please?

the errors are like theses oness:

```
Error:(7, 52) java: package com.baselet.element.facet.customdrawings.gen does not exist
Error:(8, 52) java: package com.baselet.element.facet.customdrawings.gen does not exist
Error:(9, 52) java: package com.baselet.element.facet.customdrawings.gen does not exist
Error:(11, 46) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class CustomDrawingParser
Error:(17, 40) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class CustomDrawingParserTokenManager
  location: class com.baselet.element.facet.customdrawings.CustomDrawingParserImpl
Error:(28, 40) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Provider
  location: class com.baselet.element.facet.customdrawings.CustomDrawingParserImpl
```

, later, inside the module, there is a folder called "javacc" where there is this file called CustomDrawingParser.jj, with this code:

```
    PARSER_BEGIN(CustomDrawingParser)
package com.baselet.element.facet.customdrawings.gen;

import org.slf4j.Logger;import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.baselet.control.enums.AlignHorizontal;
import com.baselet.control.enums.LineType;
import com.baselet.diagram.draw.DrawHandler;
import com.baselet.diagram.draw.helper.ColorOwn;
import com.baselet.element.facet.customdrawings.CustomDrawingParserRuntimeException;

public abstract class CustomDrawingParser {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomDrawingParser.class);

...
```

again, I do not know how should be the generation of this .gen folder... Here I leave you a pic of the project structure which I am talking about

[image]

and the project github repository: [umlet](https://github.com/umlet/umlet)

Comment: You may need to run javacc on the two .jj files to generate the corresponding java files.

Comment: It looks like you are using Maven for building.  In that case you may want to use a JavaCC plugin for Maven.  However, the simplest thing to do is likely to run javacc from the command line and copy the generated java files to the appropriate folder.

Comment: Not working.. @TheodoreNorvell

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: tried to compile it like you said and no files generated

Comment: If you ran JavaCC on the .jj files and got neither error messages nor files, I'd be very surprised. Post a minimal self-contained example as a new question.